# Printing a variable in an embedded Python interpreter

Tags: python, c, interpreter, python-c-api, python-embedding

I have written a small C program that embeds Python. I'm setting it up correctly using Py_Initialize() and Py_Finalize(), and am able to run scripts either using PyRun_SimpleString or PyRun_SimpleFile. However, I don't know how mimic the behavior of Python's own interpreter when printing variables.

Specifically:

```
a = (1, 2, 3)
print a
```

Works fine for me: it prints out (1, 2, 3)

However:

```
a = (1, 2, 3)
a
```

Prints out nothing at all. In Python's own interpreter, this would print out (1, 2, 3) as well. How can I make my code do what users would expect and print out the value?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to simulate the interpreter then. Just evaluate the input line by line and `print` the results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To run the interpreters interactive loop, you should use the function [`PyRun_InteractiveLoop()`](http://docs.python.org/c-api/veryhigh.html#PyRun_InteractiveLoop).  Otherwise, your code will behave as if it were written in a Python script file, not entered interactively.

**Edit**: Here's the full code of a simple interactive interpreter:

```
#include <Python.h>

int main()
{
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_InteractiveLoop(stdin, "<stdin>");
    Py_Finalize();
}
```

**Edit2**: Implementing a full interactive interpreter in a GUI is a bit of a project.  Probably the easiest way to get it right is to write a basic terminal emulator connected to a pseudo-terminal device, and use the above code on that device.  This will automatically get all subtleties right.

If your aim isn't a full-blown interactive editor, an option might be to use `PyRun_String()` with `Py_single_input` as start token.  This will allow you to run some Python code as in the interactive interpreter, and if that code happened to be a single expression that doesn't evaluate to `None`, a representation of its value is printed -- to stdout of course.  Here is some example code (without error checking for simplicity):

```
#include <Python.h>

int main()
{
    PyObject *main, *d;
    Py_Initialize();
    main = PyImport_AddModule("__main__");
    d = PyModule_GetDict(main);
    PyRun_String("a = (1, 2, 3)", Py_single_input, d, d);
    PyRun_String("a", Py_single_input, d, d);
    Py_Finalize();
}
```

This will print `(1, 2, 3)`.

There are still a lot of problems:

- No error handling and traceback printing.
- No "incremental input" for block commands like in the interactive interpreter.  The input needs to be complete.
- Output to stdout.
- If multiple lines of input are given, nothing is printed.

To really replicate the behaviour of the interactive interpreter is not easy.  That's why my initial recommendation was to write a basic terminal emulator in your GUI, which shouldn't be too hard -- or maybe there's even one available.

Comment: Yes, I had tried this, but it seemed to want an interactive input - unless I was doing something wrong. What I tried was:

    FILE *myfile = fopen("example.py","r+");
    PyRun_InteractiveLoop(myfile, "example.py");
    fclose(myfile);

Comment: @FizzBuzz: So you want to read commands from a file, but want them behave as if they were interactively entered?  And you claim this is what your users expect?  I'm sure I'm missing something here.

Comment: @FizzBuzz: Note that the file you pass to `PyRun_InteractiveLoop()` must be "associated with an interactive device", as the linked documentation says.

Comment: You're right; I'm just not being clear - sorry! My initial test app is on the terminal; it would be trivial to point Python at stdin and let it work. However, I would like to take it into a GUI, which should behave to the user the same way but is not so easily hooked up.

I'd like to read user input from somewhere (not stdin; a GUI text box), and have it executed in the same way as the command-line interpreter. Originally I was using PyRun_SimpleString() to send each line, but I also tried writing  commands to a file and running from there.

I hope this is clearer; thank you for your patience!

Comment: @FizzBuzz: Yes, that was really clear!  Thanks, I'll update my answer.  What platform are you on?

Comment: I'm using a Mac right now, but I'm thinking of writing something targeting either Android or iPhone depending on how things go.

Comment: @FizzBuzz: I got distracted, but I found the time to answer now.

Comment: Your second edit gives me more than enough to get started with - thank you!